# Dspace total views and download for items

Tags: dspace

First :
How I can enable total view and total download in dspace item?
Example : In this link

```
https://openknowledge.worldbank.org/handle/10986/25896
```

ABSTRACT VIEWS and FILE DOWNLOADS are enable.

I do not need exactly same but at least I can add view and download on any item of collection.

Second:
I run command : bin/dspace itemcounter and edit two changes in dspace.cfg

```
webui.strengths.show = true

webui.strengths.cache = true
```

I can view the total number of collections and items and same I like to add view and downloads for item.

Does any one have idea how this will work or any configuration change may required to do in dspace?

Many Thanks,
Faiyaz Ahmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total amount of views and downloads shown on the item pages of the Worldbank Open Knowledge Repository is not a default DSpace feature. Worldbank uses the Content & Usage Analysis module provided by Atmire to show these statistics on the item pages.

You can view item statistics by clicking on "View Usage Statistics" in the sidebar menu when you are browsing an item page.

If you would like to customise the item page or a script to show item statistics, take a look at java class org.dspace.app.xmlui.aspect.statistics.StatisticsTransformer. This is the java class responsible for rendering the "View Usage Statistics" page. In this java class you can hopefully find how the statistics are loaded and rendered.

Comment: Thank you so much for update. I will look into this.